# How to filter a pandas DataFrame for a certain column value and only return columns that do not have NAN?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Example data:

```
In [42]:    
data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'], 'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'state', 'pop', 'debt'])

Out[42]:
year    state   pop debt
0   2000    Ohio    1.5 NaN
1   2001    Ohio    1.7 NaN
2   2002    Ohio    3.6 NaN
3   2001    Nevada  2.4 NaN
4   2002    Nevada  2.9 NaN
```

I would like to filter and get a DataFrame for a certain year(say 2001) and ignore columns that have NaN as a value AND I do NOT know the names of all the columns. In the above scenario I would like

```
Out[43]:
year    state   pop
1   2001    Ohio    1.7
3   2001    Nevada  2.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt[dt['year']==2001].dropna(axis=1)
```